# GitHub secrets created using API REST but returned empty

Tags: python, github, github-actions, github-api

I created GitHub secrets using the GitHub REST API as it's given in the folowing documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets

The code that I used to `crypt` and then `create` my list of GitHub environnment secrets is te following :

```
from github import Github
import requests

access_token = base["TOKEN"]
user = gitLogin["user"]

api_url = f"https://api.github.com/users/"+user+"/repos"
response = requests.get(api_url, auth=(user, access_token))
print(response)

dev_secrets_names = [...]
dev_secrets_list = [...]
dev_encrypted_secrets_list = []

def encrypt(public_key: str, secret_value: str) -> str:
   """Encrypt a Unicode string using the public key."""
   public_key = public.PublicKey(public_key.encode("utf-8"), encoding.Base64Encoder())
   sealed_box = public.SealedBox(public_key)
   encrypted = sealed_box.encrypt(secret_value.encode("utf-8"))
   return b64encode(encrypted).decode("utf-8")

for i in range(len(dev_secrets_list)):
   encrypted_secret = encrypt(public_key, dev_secrets_list[i])
   dev_encrypted_secrets_list.append(encrypted_secret)

for i in range(len(dev_secrets_list)):
   url = f"https://api.github.com/repositories/"+"${{ steps.repos.outputs.repos_id }}"+"/environments/"+environnments["dev"]+"/secrets/"+dev_secrets_names[i]
   print(url)
   body = {"encrypted_value": f"{dev_encrypted_secrets_list[i]}", "key_id": "${{ steps.keys.outputs.key_id }}"}
   response = requests.put(url, json=body, auth=(user, access_token))
```

The code executes correctly and when I go to check the secrets are well created in GitHub. Only, when I try to retrieve the secrets in a task, they are not read as if they were empty.
The folowing code is where I'm trying to use the secrets :

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      Organization:
        required: true
        type: string
      Repository:
        required: true
        type: string
      devEnv:
        required: true
        type: string
      uatEnv: 
        required: true
        type: string
      prodEnv:
        required: true
        type: string
      devBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      uatBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      prodBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      releaseBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      rootFolder:
        required: true
        type: string
    
    secrets:
      DEV_SF_ACCOUNT:
        required: true
      DEV_SF_USERNAME:
        required: true
      DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD:
        required: true
      DEV_SF_ROLE:
        required: true
      DEV_SF_WAREHOUSE:
        required: true

deploy-snowflake-changes-dev:
    name: deploy schamas changes to dev
    needs: ShitTest 
    if: needs.ShitTest.outputs.output == 'true'
    environment: 
      name: ${{inputs.devEnv}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Python 3.8.x
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8.x

      - name: Run schemachange
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          python --version
          echo "Step 1: Installing schemachange"
          pip install schemachange

          echo "Step 3: Running schemachange"
          schemachange deploy -f ./${{inputs.rootFolder}} -a ${{secrets.DEV_SF_ACCOUNT}} -u ${{secrets.DEV_SF_USERNAME}} -r ${{secrets.DEV_SF_ROLE}} -w ${{secrets.DEV_SF_WAREHOUSE}} -d DEV_${{secrets.SF_DATABASE}} -c DEV_${{secrets.SF_DATABASE}}.${{secrets.SF_SCHEMA}}.${{secrets.SF_HISTORY_TABLE}} --vars $varsString --create-change-history-table -v  
        env:
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD }}
```

I voluntarily removed some part of the code to keep it simple.

Can you help to understand why secrets are returned as empty ?

note: when I update the secrets manually, everything works.

The following code is the one from witch I call the previous workflow :

```
jobs:
  snowflake-devops:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/snowflake-devops.yml
    with:
      Organization: $($parametersFileContent.organization)
      Repository: $($parametersFileContent.repository)
      devEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.dev)
      uatEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.uat)
      prodEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.prod)
      devBranch: ${{ env.dev }}
      uatBranch: ${{ env.uat }}
      prodBranch: ${{ env.prod }}
      releaseBranch: ${{ env.release }}
      rootFolder: $($parametersFileContent.rootFolder)
     secrets:
      TOKEN: $TOKEN
      SF_DATABASE: $SF_DATABASE
      SF_SCHEMA: $SF_SCHEMA
      SF_HISTORY_TABLE: $SF_HISTORY_TABLE
                
      DEV_SF_ACCOUNT: $DEV_SF_ACCOUNT
      DEV_SF_USERNAME: $DEV_SF_USERNAME
      DEV_SF_ROLE: $DEV_SF_ROLE
      DEV_SF_WAREHOUSE: $DEV_SF_WAREHOUSE
      DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD
```

Comment: on:
  workflow_call:

What workflow is calling this workflow?

Comment: Hello, I edited the answer to show the workflow I used to call the called workflow. Actually I think the problem is in creating the secrets by REST API and not in the way I calling the workflow because when I update the secrets with the correct values ​​workflow works fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the REST API secrets creation code?

Comment: @aknosis can you help with this topic ?

Comment: In your caller workflow, where does `$DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD` come from?

Comment: They are all variables that I created like like: $DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD = ${{ secrets.DEV_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD }}. So actually you can replace all variables whith the following syntax :  ${{ secrets.<MySecret> }}. secrets are created previously by REST API.

Comment: @samyKHEZNADJI - I am seeing this now as well with environment secrets created with the API. Did you ever find a workaround? I am working on some code that will create environment variables/secrets and when created via API, I get empty strings when attempting to access them (secrets specifically)

Answer (score 3):

Which public key value are you passing to your `encrypt` function? I just went through this scenario where the secret was being output as a blank string when attempting to use it in the workflow.

My problem was, and I'm assuming yours too, is that I was getting the [repository public key](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-repository-public-key), and not the environment public key.

Try using the [Get an Environment Public Key](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-an-environment-public-key) endpoint and saving your secret again. I was able to retrieve the value after doing that.

Comment: You saved me 2 days of searching! Thank you very much. The documentation on GitHub needs to fix some references to what types of keys should be used

Comment: My exact issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with secret creation, based on your caller workflow (the workflow at the bottom of the post). It appears you are not actually referencing the secrets correctly to pass them into the reusable workflow (`snowflake-devops.yml`).

The proper syntax would be:

```
jobs:
  snowflake-devops:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/snowflake-devops.yml
    with:
      foo: bar
     secrets:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      foo: ${{ secrets.bar }}
```

But, to save yourself more headaches, try using `secrets: inherit`. [ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow).

e.g.

```
jobs:
  snowflake-devops:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/snowflake-devops.yml
    with:
      Organization: $($parametersFileContent.organization)
      Repository: $($parametersFileContent.repository)
      devEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.dev)
      uatEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.uat)
      prodEnv: $($parametersFileContent.environnments.prod)
      devBranch: ${{ env.dev }}
      uatBranch: ${{ env.uat }}
      prodBranch: ${{ env.prod }}
      releaseBranch: ${{ env.release }}
      rootFolder: $($parametersFileContent.rootFolder)
     secrets: inherit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually it is not a problem of getting the secrets since when I update the secrets manually everything works fine. So it is a problem of creating secrets by API REST I think. Something is wrong with the code creation secrets that I wrote above.