# What am I missing when trying to update GitHub secrets through my .NET application?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to store SASToken as GitHub secret. When trying to update the secrets it is not getting updated, its always null. I'm following all steps to encrypt the value before updating in secrets, like mentioned in this link https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28.
I'm using "Create or update an environment secret [https://api.github.com/repositories/REPOSITORY_ID/environments/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/secrets/SECRET_NAME".Not](https://api.github.com/repositories/REPOSITORY_ID/environments/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/secrets/SECRET_NAME%22.Not) sure what I am missing.

Used the steps in the link to create the environment secret https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28.
But the value is not updating.

Comment: +1. I am seeing this behavior as well and I can't seem to find an official Github issue that addresses it. I'm updating some secrets a workflow and API calls, but when using those secrets they come back as empty string/null. Here is another SO post with the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74741306/1424638

Did you ever find a workaround/answer to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I posted an answer on [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76474814/1424638) but my guess is that you are using the public key for the repository, not the environment.

Try using the [Get an Environment Public Key](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-an-environment-public-key) endpoint and saving your secret again.  This appears to have worked for me, though I'm going to do more testing to double check.

Comment: Thank you for your comment about different public keys for different entities!